# What are the ramifications of right-to-left and left-to-right associativity in C based languages?

Tags: c, syntax, operators, language-design, operator-precedence

I'm in the process of writing a scripting language and I want to copy the (pretty well standardized) [C order of operations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence)

One thing that I never had a firm grasp of as a formal concept though is associativity. Why are some operator groups left-to-right and others right-to-left?

Can someone give me a few examples of how a line of code could look different if the rules were all left-to-right or the opposite of what they were? Or why the associativity is the way it is, as it seems to me just a arbitrary choice, but I assume they had a reason for it.

Also, just to note, I do know what associativity means, I just can't think of any examples where left-to-right (or vice-versa) is better than the other choice

Comment: This is such a brilliant question!. Also see [why-does-the-assignment-operator-assign-to-the-left-hand-side](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98406/why-does-the-assignment-operator-assign-to-the-left-hand-side)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the most part, each operator has the associativity that makes the most sense for that operator.

All of the non-assignment binary operators have left-to-right associativity.  This is useful for the obvious reason that English is read left-to-right and thus the evaluation of `x + y + z` is consistent with how it is read.  In addition, for arithmetic operators, the semantics match what we expect from the usage of the operators in mathematics.

Assignment operators have right-to-left associativity.  Left-to-right assignment would have bizarre and unexpected semantics.  For example, `x = y = z` would result in `x` having the original value of `y` and `y` having the original value of `z`.  It is expected that all three variables will have the same value after the expression is complete.

The prefix unary operators have right-to-left associativity, which makes sense because the operators closest to the operand are evaluated first, so in `~!x`, `!x` is evaluated first, then `~` is applied to the result.  It would be really, *really* weird were prefix operators applied with left-to-right associativity:  to say that `~!x` means evaluate `~x` and then apply `!` to the result is the complete opposite of how we think about expressions (or, at least, how most people think about expressions...).

Comment: In C, left-to-right associativity of the assignment operators would make `x = y = z` an error (for the same reason that `(x = y) = z` is an error).

Comment: @caf:  True, but if one is considering changing the associativity of an operator, one could also consider changing the value category of the operator expression.

Answer (score 6):

Examples:

```
5 - 4 - 3
(5 - 4) - 3 = -2 // left association is correct
5 - (4 - 3) = 4  // right is incorrect
```

---

```
a == b == c // What does this equal?
            // It is common to have == be non-associative because of this.
```

---

```
x = y = z
x = (y = z) // right association is correct, sets x and y
(x = y) = z // left is incorrect, does not set y
```

---

Most operators inherit their associativity from math. Bitwise can be seen as arithmetic operators and thus have left associativity.

Unary is right associative because it groups that way:

```
~!-x = ~(!(-(x)))
```

The other way wouldn't make much sense unless postfix.

Comment: I don’t like non-associativity. To my mind, `a == b == c` should mean `(a == b) == c` (compare the Boolean result of `a == b` to `c`) or be special-cased as in Python to `let b' = b in (a == b') && (b' == c)`.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky operator is exponentiation (for example: ** in python, ^ in R, haskell).  Most languages, parsers, etc view `3 ** 3 ** 3` as `3 ** (3 ** 3)`.   I personally think this is the correct interpretation, but recently noticed that both octave and matlab compute this as `(3 ** 3) ** 3`.

This is not issue in C as it does not have an exponentiation operator.  Instead you make calls to the `pow` function and have to explicitly state either `pow(3,pow(3,3))` or `pow(pow(3,3),3)`.

Comment: It is right-associative in Cobol as well, and in Fortran: http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-6.html. Mathematically speaking this is the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulated roundoff is usually the answer.

However, >> and << have to be the way they are or constructs like 12 << 2 >> 3 don't work.